# Can I create NodeMCU projects within VS Code using the PlatformIO extension?

Tags: nodemcu, platformio

I am attempting to use a ESP-32 dev kit to control WS2812 LED stripes.  Discovered there is some firmware called NodeMCU for these dev kits which uses LUA scripts from what I can tell.  There is an extension called PlatformIO for VS Code.  I had used this to program a Arduino board to flash an LED.

I was wondering if it is possible to use PlatformIO to build the NodeMCU firmware and the LUA scripts then using PlatformIO to download everything to the ESP-32 dev kit.  Is that possible?

I am thinking this can't be done since there are only two Framework selections, "Arduino" and "ESP-IDF", when I create a project which doesn't list NodeMCU.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ESP-IDF you would write C-code directly against the SDK. This can be done in Platform IO. This has its advantages but the major downside of course is that a development roundtrip takes some time. The complete build & install (flashing binary) cycle is run for every bit you turn in your source code.

With NodeMCU you build & install the firmware once and then only transfer the Lua files that changed. The downside here is that you need separate tools for separate tasks. See https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev-esp32/ for details.

1. Build the firmware, either on Linux dev env, on a Linux VM (e.g. on Windows) or with Docker (quite simple, by yours truly).
2. Flash the firmware. Use [esptool.py](https://github.com/espressif/esptool) or the self-contained standalone GUI tool [NodeMCU PyFlasher](https://github.com/marcelstoer/nodemcu-pyflasher) (by yours truly).
3. Upload Lua code from host to device. Use [ESPlorer](https://github.com/4refr0nt/ESPlorer) (very basic editor), [NodeMCU Tool](https://github.com/andidittrich/NodeMCU-Tool) or the [ChiliPeppr ESP32 Web IDE](http://chilipeppr.com/).

Comment: thanks, so basically PlatformIO and NodeMCU can't really be used together.  I had preferred to use C and call into the NodeMCU function directly, but many of them appear to be static.  From what I saw there are function tables to map LUA calls to these functions.  I did want to use a lot of the great effort people have created within NodeMCU.  I think I will end up using the NodeMCU approach as it would prove the easiest to get my XMAS lights up and running.  During searching I recall something called FastLED which would be a more pure C approach, might try it later.  Thanks!!

Comment: "PlatformIO and NodeMCU can't really be used together" - correct. If you opt for NodeMCU I suggest you look into our ws2812 LED library: https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev-esp32/modules/ws2812/